# What particle if any goes with 今 in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

There is a sentence in my textbook :

今はどこにありますか ?

It is referring to a red car.

I want to mention the red car in the sentence but if I do then the red car will take the は particle , so what becomes of 今 ?

Is it :

赤い車は今どこにありますか？

赤い車は今がどこにありますか？

赤い車の今はどこにありますか？

今の赤い車はどこにありますか？

Are any of the above sentences correct ?

What is the best way to express this ?

Answer (score 2):

The 今 is used as an adverb.
The subject is 赤い車.

So, 赤い車は今どこにありますか？ is a good expression.
今、赤い車はどこにありますか？ is also OK.